# Custom Search in asp.net mvc website

Tags: sql, search, c#-4.0

I am working on custom search for my website. So kindly guide me which technique is suitable for searching content in DB from multiple tables...

Kindly guide me the algorithms or other technique suitable for website content search.

Thnx adv

Comment: This is a hard problem. Is the data from your tables published in some form and is it publicly available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, keep in mind that this is perfectly possible, but it is **not** easy to implement.

You seem to be aware that you'll need two distinct approaches: one for dynamic content, the other for static.

For DB Search: Enable [full-text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547.aspx) on the DB side (I'm supposing you're working with SQL Server, you didn't say which DBMS you're developing with) for each "searchable" table in your DB. Create a rule that generates the right link for each table.

For static pages search: I've used [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) for that same reason, and had a good experience with it. Also, after finding the right .html file you will need a rule for generating the right link.

**Edit** You may also use some integrated library for that, like [SiteSearchASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=1464). Much easier to implement (but you'll have to pay for it).